# WPF drag drop listbox

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, panel, animated

I'm looking for a WPF drag drop library/article/tutorial that can:

1. Drag/drop to reorder list box items
2. Animate the panel as item is dragged (as shown in screen shot)

I've had a quick look at Telerik's DragDropManager, which comes with ListBoxDragDropBehavior. It provides drag/drop reordering, but not quite the behaviour as in my screenshot.

I would love to learn to write one from scratch eventually (adorners, animated panels, etc), but I'm currently time-constrained to using out-of-the-box libraries.

[image]
[image]

[edit]

The behaviour I'm looking for is the same as Windows 8's start screen

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Moving WPF DataGrid Rows using Drag and Drop](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop) which shows how to reorder DataGrid rows via drag drop and how to customize the drag indicator.